# Why do blank alert statements affect execution of other code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on the front page of a website that will have a section that will show news articles. The articles will fade into the next one every 10 seconds. For some reason the code only executes correctly (keep in mind it's not entirely finished so there may be other errors) with the inclusion of a couple alert() statements. These were previously in there just for debugging, but currently, it seems as though they serve some functional purpose. Without them, the code will give different results if any at all. 
I'm mainly a Java programmer, so there are probably some idiosyncrasies about JavaScript alert() statements that I'm not familiar with. The other odd thing that I noticed was that at times I would run the code multiple times with no changes and get different results. I used some of the alert() statements in the loadArticles() function to output the value of i and would occasionally get a different result without changing the code. The only idea I have so far is that my computer is taking time to run the statements that is allowing some other process to finish, but there shouldn't be any multi-threading involved.

The init() function is called in onload from the HTML and there's a div with id="news" somewhere in the center of the page.

On top of the main question, extra credit for anyone who could help out with why I'm sometimes not getting the articles to fade in and out. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the article or container being null, but I haven't had time to get to that yet.

Here's the JavaScript:

```
var article_count = 0;
var count = 0;

function init() {

    getArticleCount();
    loadArticles();
    changeSlide();

    resize();
    resize();

}

function getArticleCount() {

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

            article_count = xmlhttp.responseText;

        }

    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getArticleCount.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}

function loadArticles() {
    alert();
    for(i = 1; i <= article_count; i++) {
        alert();
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                alert();
                var news = document.createElement("iframe");
                news.className = "news";
                news.src = "articles/" + xmlhttp.responseText;
                news.style.zIndex = 0 - i;

                var container = document.getElementById("news");
                container.appendChild(news);

            }

        };
        alert();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "getArticles.php?q=" + i, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        alert();

    }
}

function changeSlide() {

    var article = document.getElementsByClassName("news")[count];
    var interval = setTimeout(function() {

        var fadeOut = article.fadeOut(1000, function() {

            if(count < article_count) {

                count++;
                changeSlide();

            } else {

                count = 0;
                resetSlides();

            }

        });

    }, 10000);

}

function resetSlides() {

    var articles = document.getElementsByClassName("news");

    for(j = 0; j < article_count; j++) {

        var fadeIn = articles[j].fadeIn(1000);

    }

    changeSlide();

}

function resize() {

    var body = $(document.body);
    var news = $("#news");

    $("#menu_left").width((body.outerWidth() - news.outerWidth()) / 2 - 3);
    $("#menu_right").width((body.outerWidth() - news.outerWidth()) / 2 - 3);
    $("#menu_contact").width(body.outerWidth());

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "**different results**"?

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded and alert will stop the thread.

Answer (score 6):

There are lots of mistakes in your code, mostly related to the asynchronous nature of Ajax calls.  You will need to more about programming with asynchronous operations to write correctly functioning and reliable and consistent code.

`alert()` statement change the relative timing of asynchronous operations (such as Ajax calls vs. when your other code runs.

In general, stop using `alert()` statements at all as a debugging tool because it can influence the timing too much.  Instead, use `console.log()` statements.  Since `console.log()` just outputs to the console and does not block execution of the Javascript thread at all, it will not impact the timing of things nearly as much as an `alert()` statement.

Here's a trivial example to show you how an `alert()` can change the timing of things:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://somedomain.com/myimg.jpg";
alert("Press OK to continue");
if (img.complete) {
    console.log("image is done loading");
} else {
    console.log("image is not yet done loading");
}
```

With the alert statement, you will get `image is done loading` in the console.  Without the alert, you will get `image is not yet done loading`.  The alert has changed the flow of your code.

---

Another thing that can affect the timing of your code is whether resources are in the browser cache or must be loaded over the network.  In nearly all cases, properly written code that only uses resources when it knows they have been loaded will continue to work in either case.  But, in cases with poorly written code, you may see a different behavior the first time a page is loaded vs. subsequent times when some of the resources are now cached.

---

To fix your specific code, you need to program asynchronously.  That means using completion handlers for asynchronous operations like Ajax calls and calling callbacks to notify other code when asynchronous operation are done.

For example, your `getArticleCount()` function is asynchronous.  It will finish its Ajax operation some time AFTER the `getArticleCount()` has already returned.  You can change it to accept a callback like this:

```
function getArticleCount(callback) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getArticleCount.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And, then you use it like this:

```
getArticleCount(function(cnt) {
    // in here you can use the article count
});
```

---

As for your `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()` operations, those are not native DOM methods so you can't call them on DOM objects like you are trying to do.  It appears that you are attempting to use the jQuery methods with this name.  To do, you must load jQuery into your page and then you must create jQuery objects that contain the relevant DOM objects and call `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()` on the jQuery objects, not on the DOM objects.

---

Your `loadArticles()` function can be fixed by putting the ajax calls inside an internal function inside the method.  This will allow each ajax operation you are starting to have it's own separate variables rather than having all of them collide and try to use the same variables.  You can do that by using an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) inside your `for` loop like this:

```
function loadArticles() {
    for (i = 1; i <= article_count; i++) {
        (function() {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    var news = document.createElement("iframe");
                    news.className = "news";
                    news.src = "articles/" + xmlhttp.responseText;
                    news.style.zIndex = 0 - i;
                    var container = document.getElementById("news");
                    container.appendChild(news);
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "getArticles.php?q=" + i, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        })();
    }
}
```

Note, because Ajax operations have an indeterminate timing, this code does not guarantee that the items you are adding to the page will be added in any particular order.  They are more than likely to be added in the order of your `for` loop, but that is not guaranteed.  If the serve happens to be quicker with one of the requests vs. another, it might finish first and get added to the page first, even though it was not the first one requested.

---

And, since your `resize()` function appears to use jQuery, you will find it a TON easier to use jQuery's ajax support rather than coding your own Ajax calls.  Plus with jQuery Ajax, you can use the built-in promise interface to make your asynchronous programming and error handling substantially easier.

Comment: Plus 1 for the last paragraph

Comment: Thanks for all the detail. This is definitely the kind of descriptive explanation I needed seeing as I'm not too familiar with JavaScript related technologies. I'll definitely look into jQuery's ajax and knowing about callbacks will definitely be useful. Looks like I'll definitely need to brush up on my JavaScript before finishing the project but thanks for setting me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 2):

The reason removing the `alert` calls in your code made it not work anymore is because your functions `getArticleCount()`, `loadArticles()` are making asynchronous requests for data. Alert popups made the program halt, while the AJAX request was off retrieving data and it had returned the result by the time you closed the alert popup.

You can change those 2 functions to execute a callback function as a way to let other functions know that it's finished:

```
function init() {
    getArticleCount(function() {
        // finished getting article count
        loadArticles(function() {
            // finished loading articles
            changeSlide();
            resize();
            resize();
        });
    });
}

function getArticleCount(callback) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            article_count = xmlhttp.responseText;
            callback(); // done
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getArticleCount.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function loadArticles(callback) {
    for(i = 1; i <= article_count; i++) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                var news = document.createElement("iframe");
                news.className = "news";
                news.src = "articles/" + xmlhttp.responseText;
                news.style.zIndex = 0 - i;

                var container = document.getElementById("news");
                container.appendChild(news);
                callback(); // done
            }

        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "getArticles.php?q=" + i, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }
}
```

As a side note, you can debug using the browser Developer Tools, and use `console.log()` and `debugger;`

Comment: happy to see you are still in stackoverflow. cause only links to you i have are your stackoverflow account and twitter which seems you not using much often. last time i tried to contact with you was like 4.5 years ago. By that time you were so active on stackoverflow. So as a developer i would liked to stay in touch with you. it would be so nice if we can chat a little bit about work. peace.

Answer (score 0):

XMLHttpRequest is an **asynchronous** call.

You make a `getArticleCount` request in order to get a count of articles.
Then, you have a loop:

```
for (i = 1; i <= article_count; i++) {
```

`getArticleCount` request didn't complete by the time of this loop, and `article_count` is still equal to zero. You need to use `onreadystatechange` and move your consequent dependent calls into callbacks:

```
function init() {
    getArticleCount();
}

function getArticleCount() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            article_count = xmlhttp.responseText;
            loadArticles();
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getArticleCount.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function loadArticles() {
    var container = document.getElementById("news");

    for(i = 1; i <= article_count; i++) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                var news = document.createElement("iframe");

                news.className = "news";
                news.src = "articles/" + xmlhttp.responseText;
                news.style.zIndex = 0 - i;

                container.appendChild(news);
            }

        };

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "getArticles.php?q=" + i, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

Anyway, you have some architectural problems:

- Making count request apart from data requests is redundant. Moreover, the value could change while you execute your articles.
- Making many HTTP requests will cause a huge performance drop.

You need to make a single PHP-file, which will return a JSON array with all articles. Then, you will able to work with its `length` and every item, and it will work **much** faster while not causing any synchronization problems.

Answer (score 0):

The alerts are (somewhat) syncronizing your ajax calls. You have dependencies between `getArticleCount` and `loadArticles`. The `alert()` at the top of `loadArticles` is causing execution to pause until you cancel the alert. In that time the AJAX request to "getArticleCount.php" has completed and assigned a value to `article_count`.

Without the alerts pausing execution, your code is non-deterministic b/c AJAX calls can not be strung together in a procedural fashion and behave synchronously. You will need to use a functional programming style to get AJAX calls to behave synchronously.

For example you could make write it like this

```
function init() {

    getArticleCount(loadArticles);
    resize();
    resize();

}

function getArticleCount(callback) {

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        //callback will be loadArticles()
        callback.call(null, xmlhttp.responseText);

    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getArticleCount.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}

function loadArticles(articleCnt) {

    for(i = 1; i <= articleCnt; i++) {

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                var news = document.createElement("iframe");
                news.className = "news";
                news.src = "articles/" + xmlhttp.responseText;
                news.style.zIndex = 0 - i;

                var container = document.getElementById("news");
                container.appendChild(news);
                if(i == i){
                    //modify function to use passed in count instead of global
                    changeSlides(articleCnt);
                }
            }

        };

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "getArticles.php?q=" + i, true);
        xmlhttp.send();


    }
```

}

When calling `getArticleCount` the `callback` parameter would be `loadArticles` which has been modified to accept the `article_count` as a parameter instead of using the global. The above code will fix your issue. You should modify other functions to take a local article count and stop relying on the global.